# independent keys per user in django

Tags: django

I'm new to django and I'm writing a small website for internal use. The basic functionality is to get permission and access the user google account (photos, drive, etc).

In my views.py I need to share some variables between the different functions (for example, the access key to the google account). I implemented this by using a global variable (a class with data fields only). This solutoin works nicley exept one big problem: if two users use the website at the same time, both access the same google account!

How can I make sure each user will have his own private data?
(by user I mean someone that access the site on his personal computer)

Thanks, Shimi

Comment: Put it in the database, or the session.

Comment: I tried to avoid database (less to learn when I'm just strating). And can you please refer me to where I can learn on sessions?

Comment: Well you won't get very far with Django if you won't use the database. The sessions docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: I know, but I thought I could start without ;-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In a typical python web application (Django, Flask etc) production setup your code will be executed by at least half a dozen processes, and any request can be served by any of those processes, so you just cannot rely on globals to store / share state between requests - globals are per-process, and you don't know which process will serve the user's next request. This is why we use a database as a way to persist data and make them available to all the server processes. As Daniel mentions in his comment, you won't get very far with Django (nor Flask etc) if you don't use the database.

To make a long story short:

> How can I make sure each user will have his own private data

Quite simply: write a model (or more) for your user's "own private data".

Comment: OK. Thanks for the fast replay!